# Is there any *.csv File manager with Treeview

Tags: python-3.x, csv, notepad++, text-editor, qtreewidget

Is there any Notepad++ plugin, separate software or something else what can manage and show me csv file as treeview (can edit this csv file ,delete some lines, edit name, etc) ?

O - folder

V - file

1, 2, 3, 4 - level

Example:

```
O;1;Folder_Master;;
    O;2;Folder_in second_level;;
        V;3;File1_in_third_level
        O;3;Folder_in_third_level
             V;4;File2_in_4_level
             V;4;File3_in_4_level
        O;3;Folder_in_third_level
             V;4;File4_in_4_level
             V;4;File5_in_4_level
        O;3;Folder_in_third_level
             V;4;File6_in_4_level
             V;4;File7_in_4_level
        O;3;Folder_in_third_level
             V;4;File8_in_4_level
             V;4;File9_in_4_level
```

Comment: I would advise on using a spreadsheet like excel or libreoffice. There are import functions for csv and other text formats. You can sort and filter the rows. In notepad++ and in spreadsheets you can delete lines and edit names. I dont know about the treeview thing.

Comment: No it's not that way.
I'm already working with Notepad++. But when I have more than 400 000 lines, than is not easy delete one folder with 1 000 file/lines.
For example, if one folder contain 1 000 line, will be easier to close this tree (hide 1 000 lines with one mouse click).
In my question is this structure example.

Comment: Is the file indented like in the example? Then you can choose Python from the Language menu and use the folding feature (the related commands from the view menu und clicks on the minus and plus signs on the left border). If the file is not indented, you could use some search and replace to add 1 tab for level 2, two tabs for level 3 and so on.

Comment: @LarsFischer No, unfortunately the file don't have indented. Can you show me some example how do you want to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this will work for you. But I think of using the Language -> Python and then use its folding feature. Python structures code by indentation and you can fold away all details (that is hide some level of indentation completely) or hide something by selecting it individually.

First we need indentation, do a regular expression search and replace:

1. replace `^(.;2;)` with `\t\1`
2. replace `^(.;3;)` with `\t\t\1`
3. replace `^(.;4;)` with `\t\t\t\1`

Then select Language -> Python and play around with the Folding feature:

- Click on the minus-symbols in the left fringe
- Use the View -> Fold and Collapse Options

In the end, remove the indentation with Edit->Blank Operations -> Trim Leading Space.

Comment: One or two times I can do that, but I will be work often with this type of file.
Maybe will be better write some code in python ?
I found something like `qtreewidget`. The question is or this tool will help me to manage this type of files. And what will be better PySide or PyQt ?